# I can't download/install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I want to download and install the 32 bit version over my desktop running XP.  The file that it downloads is called
      ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso

It is from ftp.citylink.co.nz, and it is 895 MB.

Windows has no idea what to do with a .iso file, and neither do I.  I certainly can't double click on it and run anything.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the linked Q&A - you need to use burning software to write the  image to DVD or via USB - http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't download a file from an unknown source. Instead, go to https://www.ubuntu.com to get the download file. (If you're here I assume you trust the .ubuntu.com TLD).